# Errors: Installing a .deb without sudo/root

Tags: ubuntu, debian, deb, dpkg

I have created a .deb package, and I am trying to deploy it without any using sudo/root privileges. However, I am receiving `Permission denied` messages, and I do not know what `dpkg` is doing and what is causing it.

Running `dpkg -i --force-not-root --root=$HOME/a --log=$HOME/a/log a.deb` returns:

```
(Reading database ... 0 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking tetra-backup (from a.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing a.deb (--install):
 unable to open '/home/simon/a/simon_exec.dpkg-new': Permission denied
Errors were encountered while processing:
 a.deb
```

Here is the content of the deb (`$ dpkg --contents a.deb`):

```
drwxrwxr-x simon/simon       0 2013-09-17 14:49 ./
-r--r--r-x simon/simon    5568 2013-09-16 15:46 ./simon_exec
```

I want to know what I need to do to resolve the mentioned issue and to deploy the contents under such constraints. If it's not possible, I would like to know why and some alternatives.

Comment: Does `$HOME/a` exist?  Do you have permissions to write there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing with `--force-not-root` is likely to give you lots of problems. dpkg will most likely not be able to resolve a lot of package dependencies, or install files to certain locations outside of your home directory.

One thing you could try is doing `apt-get source <package>` and configure it to install locally. This might require you do download and compile all of its dependencies as well though. You will also need the dev tools installed to do it this way.

Comment: Or if you want to check out the package informally, set up a suitable virtualization environment (KVM, VMware, what have you) and have all the root access you need inside a temporary box.

Comment: Or a [`dchroot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/en/man1/dchroot.1.html).